# Should I always include this._super(...arguments) when overwriting an Ember member function

Tags: ember.js

In Ember.js, there are a lot of functions that require you to call this._Super(...arguments) before calling them. A [quick example](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/getting-started/core-concepts/#toc_hooks) from the documentation:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  didRender() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    console.log('I rendered!');
  }
});
```

Are there ever cases in Ember where we do not need to call `this._super()`? The reason I ask is because often times, I will write some hooks for either my controllers or routes where I simply forget to call `this._super(...arguments)` and, as far as I can tell, everything works the same.

Should I always include a `super()` method before overwriting any member function in Ember?

Comment: I may be the odd one out, by I _only_ use super in the constructor and init. https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/emberclear/search?q=super&unscoped_q=super (that search does include a didInsertElement, but I'm extending a non top-level component class

Comment: I almost always do. In a long lost thread someone once told me that the behavior of the overridden method was not necessarily guaranteed by semver so I should always call super to avoid strangeness in the future if something was added to an upstream method that is currently doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you better include `this._super`, although it is not "a must" in most cases.

There is only one place I know where this is *critical* - `init`. Most probably `constructor` too, as mentioned above, but I never needed to overwrite a constructor. However, consider this:

1. As many people mentioned, something might be changed in future versions and including `this._super` may help to avoid bugs
2. If you use mixin from some ember addon, they might also overwrite ember methods or do it in future versions
3. Let's say you are extending component from your own mixin and right now your mixin does not overwrite `didRender`. But what if you will need to change that in future?

So, while in most cases including `this._super` is not critical, it is good to include it anyway. Except cases when you intended to completely overwrite default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In a long lost thread someone once told me that the behavior of the overridden method was not necessarily guaranteed by semver so I should always call super to avoid strangeness in the future if something was added to an upstream method that is currently doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should always do so. If you don't, ember won't execute the code that handles behind the scenes stuff which will result in weird behaviour you might not be able to debug..

P.S : As an experiment just try overriding a setupController method in any route in your app without calling this._super(...arguments) and see what happens.

Comment: "As an experiment just try overriding a `setupController` method in any route" - Did that a lot. Nothing really bad happens, unlike with `init`.

Comment: @Gennady Dogaev Which version of ember are you using?

Comment: Any, version does not matter. All setupController does by default is setting `model` on controller. You can do that w/o `this._super` or use some other property instead of `model`

Comment: Please check the following ember twiddle. i have overridden setupController and not used this._super() because of which " All setupController does by default is setting model on controller." does not happen and nothing gets displayed on the screen.
https://ember-twiddle.com/fe482c342f61f6361d48fd3a4b2f72ba?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C

Comment: Of course nothing is displayed because you are trying to use model and did not add code that sets it. Check [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/4532ba097eab3b5dc1ad2c79e13d5ce6?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) - all works and there is no 'this._super'

Comment: Exactly the point i was trying to make. You had to explicitly set it because you overrode the method and did not use 'this._super'. what you did can be done by simply calling 'this._super'. This is the purpose of the setupController as intended by the creators of Ember and thats what the OP was asking about.